# Simplest way to transfer files from PC to Android device (wireless)

Tags: applications, wi-fi, file-transfer, ftp

What's the simplest way to transfer files (often around 100 MB) from PC to Android device, **with wireless connexion** ?

Should I use an application for this?

*Remark 1 : I want to set "wifi=off" after the file transfer is done, because I never use it except for the file transfer. Moreover I really would like to do a direct transfer PC -> Android device ; no Dropbox or similar tool.*

*Remark 2 : I have a Samsung Galaxy 3.6 Player YP-GS1CB (limited to Android 2.x as far as I know)*

*Remark 3 : If possible, I would like to be able to see the Android device's microSD card filesystem from computer, access to subdirectories, copy files there, etc.    Would a FTP server on the Android device be a good way to do it ? If so, with which app?*

Comment: There's a ton. You could use one of the cloud sync apps (Dropbox, Google Drive, Copy, etc.), you could use one of the Android remote control apps (Airdroid, etc.). Even some of the file managers have a way to get to shared drives on your wifi network (ES File Explorer, ASTRO, etc.) Did you try searching on the Play Store? Also, simplest is pretty subjective; we prefer questions that garner objective answers.

Comment: Thanks @AlE. I added some remarks at the beginning of the question in order to make it more precise.

Answer (score 3):

[Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) can perform file transfers and it runs on 2.2 and above.

All features:

- SMS: send and receive individual or group messages.
- Apps: Import and export .apk files.
- Files: Manage files on Android and transferring files between Android and computer.
- Photos: View and manage photos on Android and transferring photos between Android and computer.
- Music & Videos: Play and manage music & videos on Android and transferring them between Android and computer.
- Ringtones: Set music as ringtone and export any ringtone.
- Contacts: View and edit all the contacts.
- Screenshot: View the real time screen of Android devices, take static screenshots. (root required)
- Camera: See through the lens of both front and back camera, also supports flashlight.
- URL: Push url to Android and open automatically open it with Android browser.
- Clipboard: Share clipboard content between Android and computer.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking around for ages after an adequate solution and was frustrated to find no official apps that provide this functionality.

[Link to PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hub/4529948/your-phone-app-help) changed everything.
It's a Microsoft app that allows you to use your phone from your PC.
It supports a wide variety of features, including screen-casting, file-transfer by drag and drop, send and receive messages and phone calls and more.

I might sound like Microsoft's salesman but I have no affiliation whatsoever, I'm just a fan of this app that made life so easier for me.

Answer (score -1):

I developed [WiFi FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver.pro), which should solve your problem. I would recommend that you put the phone in wifi-tether mode and then transfer files.